# Windows 10 can't search for apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

On a fresh install of windows 10 (final build), my "search windows" is broken..

It won't find any of my apps when I search. E.g. "sublime" for sublime text, "internet" for IE, nothing. WHen I click "search my stuff" and filter to "apps", I get a "Something went wrong".

I've turned Cortana off, and web results. I've rebuilt my search index, and changed the locations to make sure it's searching in places I know the start menu to be... I've also run the windows troubleshooter, with no joy.

Comment: Re-install Windows (as it's a new install)

Comment: It *looks* like a dupe, my situation is slightly different 'cos 1) I get a "something went wrong" msg, and 2) I get slightly different behavior returned.